# CKEditor on dynamically created p elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to dynamically add p elements and make them editable with the CKEditor. However when I try the following code the editor does not show up.

```
 var div = document.getElementById(divId);  
 div.innerHTML = '<p id="vbText'+ divId +'">Example text</p>';
 document.getElementById('vbText' + divId).contentEditable = "true";        
 CKEDITOR.inline('vbText' + divId);
```

Comment: Before the call to .inline, does the rendered HTML look good? Does it work if you copypaste it to a separte static html file and try to CKEDITify it there?

Comment: Do you have the id of the div assigned to divId variable? 
`var divId = "SomeDiv";`
Everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: You can also try CKEDITOR.inline( document.getElementById( 'vbText' + divId) );

Comment: I found the problem, it doesn't show because I'm making a div above that draggable with jquery, once I remove the draggable it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, it work for me:

```
var node = document.getElementById('editor'),
div = document.createElement("div"),
h2 = document.createElement("h2");
h2.textContent = "Text";
div.appendChild(h2);
div.setAttribute('contenteditable','true');
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(div, config);
node.appendChild(div);
```

Good luck!